# Decrypting with openssl_private_decrypt wont work because text is storing apostrophes

Tags: php, mysql, openssl, encryption

I store sensitive information in a mysql database in 'text' field format which is encrypted using openssl_public encrypt and descrypted using openssl_private_decrypt.

The issue I face however is that when trying to use my php script to 'decode' the text, the returned value has several apostrophes and quotations within it, therefore making the decryption impossible. Any ideas how to fix this?

Note: I initially tried to store my information in field type 'varbinary' but the decryption failed every time doing so.

After reviewing some more, I think perhaps php and mysql are having a hard time processing all the information (~800 records) because sometimes fields are left blank, othertimes not. If I store one by one, it works with zero issues but when trying to run through the foreach loop it almost always causes errors. Any ideas? Script to encode is below:

```
<?php

$publickey = file_get_contents("certificate.pem");

function encrypt($text) 
    { 
        return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, SALT, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND)))); 
    } 


    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME', 'USER', 'PW');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->beginTransaction();

        $start = microtime(true);

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ID, ITEM1_old, ITEM2_old  FROM tablename");

        $stmt->execute();

        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach($rows as $row) {

            $id = $row['0'];
            $item1 = $row['1'];
            $item2 = $row['2'];

            define('SALT', $id);

            $item1_enc = encrypt($item1);
            $item2_enc = encrypt($item2);

            openssl_public_encrypt($item1_enc, $item1_ssl_enc, $publickey);
            openssl_public_encrypt($item2_enc, $item2_ssl_enc, $publickey);

            $stmt2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE tablename SET ITEM1_new=?, ITEM2_new=? WHERE ID=?");
            $stmt2->execute(array($item1_ssl_enc, $item2_ssl_enc, $id));

        }   

        $db->commit();
        $db->NULL;

        $elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;
        echo "Finished.<br />Elapsed time: ".$elapsed;
    }

    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $db->rollback();
        echo "There was a system error.".$e->getMessage();          
    }
?>
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with quotes. These functions don't treat them any different than any other character. Perhaps a code sample and actual error message or better description of the problem would help. Are you doing anything to these strings other than using openssl_public_encrypt and openssl_private_decrypt on them?

Comment: @Dan - there is no error message either on the page or in apache error log. I will put together a modified version of the script but the overall checks and balances within the page is nearly 600 lines long. I'll summarize.

Comment: Some records are even skipped COMPLETELY  for ITEM1 when running through the foreach loop while ITEM2 for the same record is not

Comment: If I were you, I'd start off with something simpler and add a lot of debugging output. You're doing all kinds of little things that probably don't cause a problem but might, like calling functions that don't exist, accessing array keys that don't exist but might after casting, thinking you're nulling variables that you aren't (and should be using unset), etc. Print things out before you even insert anything into a database or you have no idea where they go wrong.

Comment: @Dan - did that too. I *think* I found the problem as it relates to different variables calling the same function and 'perhaps' overwriting previous variables (which truthfully doesn't make sense but when changed it temporarily resolves my issue). In short, $abc = function($var1) and $def= function($var2) seem to be causing conflict issues in the foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the ciphers encrypt in blocks, if your plain text does not mesh up with the block size of the cipher, it will get padded out. This is normal and correct, what you need to to is pack a length field into the data before you encrypt it like so.

```
$plaintext  = 'text to encrypt';
$plaintext  = pack('V', strlen($plaintext)) . $plaintext;
$ciphertext = encrypt($plaintext);
```

Then to get the output back:

```
$plaintext = decrypt($ciphertext);
$header    = unpack('Vsize', $plaintext);
$plaintext = substr($plaintext, 4, $header['size'] + 4);
```

Also, if your payload is more then a hundred bytes or less, you should not use RSA to encrypt the entire payload, you should generate a random key, encrypt the payload with the key, and then encrypt the key with your public/private key. RSA is not designed to encrypt large payloads, it is designed to share a secret to initialize a faster symmetric cipher such as Blowfish.

Eg.

```
/* Generate the random key */
$key = '';
for($i = 0; $i < 255; ++$i)
  $key .= chr(mt_rand(0, 255));
$key = sha1($key);

/* Pack & encrypt the payload with the key */
$plaintext  = pack('V', strlen($plaintext)) . $plaintext;
$ciphertext = encrypt($plaintext, $key);

/* Encrypt the key with the public key */
$key     = public_encrypt($key);
$payload = pack('V', strlen($key)) . $key . $ciphertext;
```

To decrypt

1. unpack the payload key length
2. decode the encrypted key using the public key
3. decode the ciphertext using the decrypted key.